# IBDesignable properties not updating during runtime

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom segmented control using this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGdRCUrSu94&t=2502s) . I want to be able to change the string values displayed inside the custom segmented control (commaSeperatedButtonTitles) during runtime from 1,2,3,4 to 5,6,7,8 but for some reason the view is not updating the values. The values seem to be able to be changed in viewDidLoad but not inside action events which is what I need.

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class CustomSegmentedControl: UIControl {

var buttons = [UIButton]()
var selector: UIView!
var selectedSegmentIndex = 0

@IBInspectable
var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet{
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
    didSet{
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}
@IBInspectable
var commaSeperatedButtonTitles: String = "" {
    didSet{

    }
}

@IBInspectable
var textColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
    didSet{
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var selectorColor: UIColor = .blue {
    didSet{

    }
}

@IBInspectable
var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .white {
    didSet{

    }
}

func updateView(){

    buttons.removeAll()
    subviews.forEach { (view) in
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    var buttonTitles = commaSeperatedButtonTitles.components(separatedBy: ",")

    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttons.append(button)
    }

    buttons[0].setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)

    let selectorWidth = (frame.width / CGFloat(buttonTitles.count))
    selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectorWidth, height: frame.height))
    selector.layer.cornerRadius = (frame.height / 2)
    selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
    addSubview(selector)


    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
    sv.axis = .horizontal
    sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.distribution = .fillEqually
    addSubview(sv)

    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    layer.cornerRadius = (frame.height / 2)
    //updateView()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    updateView()
}

func buttonTapped(button: UIButton){
    for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
        btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
        if btn == button{
            selectedSegmentIndex = buttonIndex
            let selectorStartPosition = (frame.width / CGFloat(buttons.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
                self.selector.frame.origin.x = selectorStartPosition
            })
            btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
        }
    }
    sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
}


}
```

Code in View Controller inside action event:

```
 customSegment.commaSeperatedButtonTitles = "5,6,7,8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that `updateView()` method is not being called after you set the `commaSeperatedButtonTitles` property. Try calling it after the property is set:

```
@IBInspectable
var commaSeperatedButtonTitles: String = "" {
    didSet {
        self.updateView()
    }
}
```

Another point worth mentioning: it's probably unnecessary to call `updateView()` every time on `layoutSubviews()` as it recreates all the buttons for your custom segmented control.

Comment: Thank you, that is a strange that it wasn't getting called. Will removing updateView from layoutSubviews not affect the functionality of the custom segment? thanks for the advice

Comment: Removing this `updateView()` call is likely going to affect the behavior only if you don't set the `commaSeparatedButtonTitles` after your custom segmented control has been initialized. So it depends on how you're using it. To make it a bit more robust I would assign a default value to `commaSeparatedButtonTitles` in the initializer or in the `awakeFromNib()` method.

Comment: Hi Misha, I have noticed now that when using the above answer that this actually stops the animation between the custom segments. Any idea why this would happen? I have tried every work around I can think of and it is not correcting the issue.

Comment: So if you comment out the code I’ve suggested, you see the animation? I doubt though it’s the reason because you should not reset the commaSeparatedButtonTitles when switch value is changed.

Comment: Yes that single line causes the animation to not appear. Any ideas for a work around to this? I have tried to find a solution but cannot

Comment: To find it out, I’d place a breakpoint in the `commaSepratedButtonTitles didSet {}` part and see who calls the setter observer when user taps on the segmented control. Unfortunately, I didn’t find any issues after another glimpse through the code.